# Get SSH one-liner commands to show color

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, colors

I'd like to enable colored text output on SSH one-liner commands, but I can't seem to get it to work on OS X, Ubuntu 14.10, or OpenSUSE 12.2.

If I ssh into a server and type, say, `ls --color=auto` in the prompt, it works just fine, showing directories, symlinks, and regular files in different colors, however, if I put the command in an ssh one-liner on the same system: `ssh user@host "ls --color=auto"`, the output isn't colored.

Typing `echo $TERM` gives me `xterm-256color` whether or not I put it in a one-liner statement.

This is mainly for color-coding errors and warnings on remote builds, but it would be nice to get it enabled for everything.

Any advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ssh user@host "ls --color=auto"
```

`ls` only outputs colors when it is writing to a terminal. When you specify a command for `ssh` to run on the remote host, ssh doesn't allocate a TTY (terminal interface) by default. So, when you run the above command, ssh doesn't allocate a terminal on the remote system, ls sees it's not writing to a terminal, and it doesn't output colors.

You can run ssh with the `-t` option to make it allocate a terminal. The following should print colors:

```
ssh -t user@host "ls --color=auto"
```

If `ssh` is being run non-interactively, and is own local output isn't going to a terminal, then it will ignore a single `-t` flag. In this case, you can specify `-t` more than once to force ssh to allocate a TTY on the remote system:

```
ssh -tt user@host "ls --color=auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use `--color=always` in case of ls, to force color.
And to have colors in other apps, thatt support coloring, but do not support for `--color=value`, you can also try to `ssh <host> -t "TERM=${TERM} <command>"`